# Is it ok to listen to music written by someone who's anti-semitic?

Tags: music, performance-entertainment, anti-semitism

Wagner was anti-semitic but made some great music; is it wrong to listen to it? Could one still say the music is great?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure who Wagner is, exactly, but there might be an issue to [praise a non-Jew](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36297/is-praising-non-jews-actually-prohibited). There's also issues with [listening to non-Jewish music](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/sources-for-listening-to-not-listening-to-non-jewish-music). As for anti-Semitic... Isn't that usually an issue of intent? I'm assuming you're an upstanding Jew, or else you wouldn't be asking this question, so I'm also assuming you're not a self-hating Jew...

Comment: @DonielF I support the jews and Israel.And are aginst all anti semitic doctrine,music is  very spiritual .So what then if the artist behind the music is anti-semitic?

Comment: I was hoping you'd say that. Like I said in my comment, I'm not exactly sure how Wagner's anti-semitism filters into his music, but I can tell you that the fact that he's not Jewish could pose some issues.

Comment: @DonielF Viewing the linked M.Y. question about listening to non-Jewish music, it seems that there are a number of conditions that R. Feinstein lists that would prohibit the music. However, I don;t think any of these apply to listening to solely instrumental classical music. Case in point - numerous Jewish songs including some that are part of Nusach Ashkenaz prayer services originated from non-Jewish sources. One of Chabad's tunes uses "Le Marsailles" - a French "secular" tune.

Comment: Wagner's Der Ring Des Nibelungen may be problematic due to its exploration and use of characters depicting Germanic mythology and paganism.

Comment: @JJLL Thats very interesting

Comment: But would you buy a Ford (car)?But I guess a car is not that spiritual as music.I would say an anti jewish  work of art has an evil spirit behind it.

Comment: On the face of it @Eagle, at least in Broolkyn, it appears that the overwhelming majority of Ashkenazis won't buy German-made cars but don't have ANY difficulty purchasing Ford products despite International Jew and Dearborn Independent fame. For many American males, cars are spiritual in a certain sense

Comment: Oh, for that matter, the same Jews who won't buy BMW or Mercedes (Sephardim don't seem to have any qualms) do purchase Hugo Boss clothing from Orthodox Jewish clothing stores and fedoras made by that Spabish company whose name eludes me (I think it begins with B) despite Hugo Boss having the contract to manufacture uniforms for the nazis http://www.nytimes.com/1997/08/15/business/hugo-boss-acknowledges-link-to-nazi-regime.html and Spain responsible for the Expulsion.