# Does positively critiquing a business (owned by non-jews) fall under the prohibition of "not to grant them favor?"

Tags: halacha, gentiles

The Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh Dead 151:14 (seemingly based on Devarim 7:2 and Meseches Avodah Zarah 20a) states that it's forbidden to praise a non-jew, including their actions.

Does this issur include critiquing a business, where such a critique includes positive elements (e.g the company does "x" well, etc.)? In a similar vein, would this prohibition include critiquing the personnel (e.g the employees do "x" well, etc.)?

Comment: relevant: [Sefer HaChinuch 426](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.426.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: related and possible duplicate of [Is praising non-Jews actually prohibited?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36297/11501)

Comment: relevant: http://www.torahlab.org/Community/article/lo_sichaneim_do_not_grant_them_favor/ https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5773-noach/